# can I secure Android application by using random number generator way?

Tags: android, security

To more secure my App. actually I follow these steps (I wanna to secure my app. without using server check):

1. First of all, I give the user test period, to test app. Then, if the user want to work on it and use it, the  next steps required.
2. I use a complex random generate function to generate a number with six digits.
3. I display this number on screen (as Log In screen) for user.
4. Then, ask user to enter the number, to can access app.
5. After that, compare to see if the user input number as one generated by some equation in the code (I am one who give user this number when he want to install app).
6. If are equal then the user can access the app.
7. Else, exit app.

**Now**, what I wanna to inquire about please:

1. by this way can I secure my app from install again
2. or can this way broke in anyway by another programs etc.?
3. or if there is another way, useful sites, etc. to achieve that

thanks,

Comment: how about just releasing 2 versions of the app to the store. One for free, for testing. One that is paid for and will always work. Much easier, much more secure. "never roll your own security protocol" is correct

Comment: yes I thought in that really, but it was not acceptable for my company !! Thanks ...

Comment: Bear in mind that if your customer has to PAY to get access to the app, then Google needs to get their cut of that payment. AFAIK it is in the terms & conditions of the Play store that we cannot let users get paid access to our apps without paying Google their %.

Answer (score 0):

It's insecure, period.

For stuffs of any significant value, [never roll your own security protocol.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)

Otherwise, don't bother securing your app. Most people are honest, it's fine if a few people steal your app, it won't hurt your bottom line.

Comment: yes, thanks for your explanation. But, for the people yes I am with you for that,, BUT the app for the company (where I work) not my own! cause that I search for algorithm and way to find a procedure that can be approved and acceptable for them...

Comment: @MaheeraJazi: Does not matter if it's your company's app; it's your job to explain that there is no such thing as secure offline program validation. Lots of companies (Microsoft, Adobe, etc) tried it during the 1990s and early 2000s, all that that does is become training program for junior crackers. Nowadays they all uses either online validation or put some of the critical parts as a web service in their own web server.

Comment: yes, actually I know that .. I am trying just trying to provide app a very simple verification ,, also I explain that for them, but they still need such procedure to ask user for a number before can use app.  !!! until now this will help (as I think :( ) ... thanks again

Comment: @MaheeraJazi: explain to them that entering those numbers does not can never add any shred of security but only false sense of security. Also explain to them that asking the user for those numbers also significantly compromises ease of use and is user-hostile (the user will perceive it that you don't trust them). Just focus on making the best application experience possible, and don't worry about people stealing the app. Unless you're creating an app that will top on all app stores, your best bet at protection is your relative obscurity that nobody will bother to attempt to crack the app.

Comment: yes Thanks really for this explanation ...But really I wondered if this will be a challenge in future to work on !